# How to make TypeScript happy with extending classes imported from 'node modules'?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server

Edit: Added `ARTICLES_QUERY`, `tsconfig.json` and `package.json` as requested

Edit 2: This works, but it seems an ugly solution.  If anyone has a better one I'd be grateful

```
export default class InterfaceGraphQLApi extends GraphQLDataSource {
  baseURL = "http://localhost:4545/admin/api";

  query = super.query;
```

Edit 3: @Max's solution solves the problem with the query field, but it leads to TS not compiling the source due to another 'error':
[image]

`ARTICLE_QUERY` here is

```
const ARTICLE_QUERY = gql`
  query Article($id: ID!) {
    Article(where: { id: $id }) {
      title
      text
      video {
        youtube {
          ... on OEmbedVideo {
            html
            type
          }
        }
      }
      podcast {
        spotify {
          ... on OEmbedRich {
            html
            type
          }
        }
      }
      images {
        file {
          filename
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Edit 4: Max's edited solution works fine.

---

I'm relatively new to TypeScript.  I'm importing a [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-datasource-graphql) that allows me to define a GraphQL data source for my Apollo Server project. In my project I'm extending the class that this library defines

```
 import { GraphQLDataSource } from "apollo-datasource-graphql";
import { gql } from "apollo-server";

const ARTICLES_QUERY = gql`
  query {
    allArticles {
      title
      text
      id
      status
      images {
        file {
          filename
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default class InterfaceGraphQLApi extends GraphQLDataSource {
      baseURL = "http://localhost:4545/admin/api";

      async getArticles() {
        try {
          const response = await this.query(ARTICLES_QUERY);
```

However TypeScript complains about `this.query`, saying

[image]

The `query` method comes from the imported library's class.  How do I resolve this to make TypeScript happy?

tsconfig.json is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

and package.json is

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "apollo-datasource-graphql": "^1.3.2",
    "apollo-server": "^2.10.1",
    "graphql": "^14.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^14.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.2",
    "pino": "^5.16.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "ramda": "^0.26.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsc && node dist/index.js"
  }
}
```

In addition, I'm wondering if anyone could steer me towards the type definitions I'll need for Apollo Server and GraphQL -- I searched for 'type definitions Apollo Server' and came up with [this](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/blob/master/packages/apollo-server-core/src/types.ts), but it has many dependencies I'd also have to find and download.  I was wondering if there were anything like `@types/apollo-server` (when I did `yarn @types/apollo-server`,  I got   `https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types%2fapollo-server: Not found.`).

Thanks for any info!

Comment: Could you please add your ARTICLES_QUERY to your question?

Comment: @Max -- Added it

Comment: does `Typescript` complains at runtime ?

Comment: @FahdLihidheb, it won't compile

Comment: And gql comes from `import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express';`?
And GraphQLDataSource comes from `import { GraphQLDataSource } from 'apollo-datasource-graphql';`?

Comment: and posting your tsconfig and package.json would be helpfull to answer your question. I already created a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-zdysny, where it compiles

Comment: @Max, I've added `tsconfig.json` and `package.json`.  I'll look at your code

Comment: @Max, yes, those are the correct imports, I've added them.  My code still doesn't compile.  `datasources/GraphQLDataSource.ts:59:35 - error TS2339: Property 'query' does not exist on type 'InterfaceGraphQLApi'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open PR in the apollo-datasource-graphql repo: https://github.com/poetic/apollo-datasource-graphql/pull/11

There is a solution which helps you in the meantime. Change your import from:

`import { GraphQLDataSource } from 'apollo-datasource-graphql';`

to

`import { GraphQLDataSource } from 'apollo-datasource-graphql/src';`

And finally, I found an interesting part during the research. I found a section in the docs from [apollo server](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/data-sources/) where you can define an api as a ressource and not a graphql server. Which is actually the case in your provided code.

In Addition, if you have other issues that might block tsc from compiling, please go under your node_modules into the apollo-datasource-graphql folder and go to the query function. There is the desired type for the options parameter. And as the docs say you need to provide the query you passed as first parameter also in the options as a query like this

`const response = await this.query(ARTICLE_QUERY, { query: ARTICLE_QUERY,  variables: { id }});`

Comment: that solved the original issue, but led to another issue that prevents TS from compiling.  I edited the original question to point out that error.  Thanks for pointer to those docs -- as I understand it that is only for REST sources, hence the need for `apollo-datasource-graphql` ?

Comment: @Cerulean: If you have further questions, please open a stackblitz or typescript playground that I can help you with. The query in your first question was answered and as you changed the query another issue appears. Or open a github repo where I can help you with. I changed the answer to your last edit.

Comment: If I need anything further I will try to upload something. I added the field `query` to `options` and it works great.   However I'm now getting `Error: Cannot find module 'apollo-datasource-graphql/src'` when I try to compile and compilation halts.  It worked before, very strange.